# Lcov Unit Coverage report upload into SonarQube

Tags: c++, sonarqube, lcov

**Our SonarQube Environment details as follows:**

```
SonarQube Version – 6.7.5(LTS).
sonar-cxx-plugin-1.1.0.jar (Community Plugin).
```

Using `C++ language` and coverage generated in both `.info & .html`(`generated from genhtml command`). Tried to upload the lcov coverage `.info & .html` both the format on SonarQube separately, But didn’t work.

1)  Seems uploading directly `.info & .html` based reports not possible into sonarqube.

2)  So should I convert them into xml format as instructed by this link --> https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml

3)  Or Suggest the best way to upload lcov coverage report into Sonarqube for C++.